# javascript Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am getting the following error in Google Chrome on a very old Form I inherited (seems to work OK in IE, no errors)

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null

The error applies to the following js **elem.firstChild.nodeValue = dispmessage;**:

```
function msg(fld,     
         msgtype, 
         message) {
  if (emptyString.test(message))
    dispmessage = String.fromCharCode(nbsp);
  else
    dispmessage = message;

  var elem = document.getElementById(fld);
  elem.firstChild.nodeValue = dispmessage;

  elem.className = msgtype;   // set the CSS class to adjust appearance of message
};
```

Wondering if someone has come across similar issue before? Any ideas on how I can resolve?

Cheers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This error means the `elem` object is `null`. Check the fld value passed and see whether an object with that id actually exists in your code or not.

Comment: or in simple ways: your javascript is loading way before your html and thus, javascript is not able to find the DOM Element. Cheers ;-)