# Display gridview on the basis of columns and rows entered

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two textbox where user can enter `No of Rows` and `No of Columns`. 
and one dropdown for Abbrevation as `"A-Z"`

So if user enters

*1st textbox ---   5*

*2nd textbox ---  5*

and selects abbr as "A-Z"

So in gridview it should display as

[image: Gridview display]

any idea pls suggest how to start.

Comment: You also want the curves? Sorry, i could not resist :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter: its just a diagrammatic representation. just need the matrix

Comment: This is too broad. You haven't shown what you've tried so far. So there's currently no issue to fix but just a requirement for us.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I only want ideas, that how to combine the abbrevation and display. If any please suggest. I m still not getting any errors

Comment: You could fill a `DataTable` with rows and columns according to the user input. `int cols=int.Parse(txtCol.Text);for(int i=0; i<cols;i++) table.Columns.Add("Col"+i.ToString());`. Then fill the rows similarly according to `txtRows.Text` input. Your logic is still not so clear. Why `A11` and not `A1`, what happens if rows/columns exceed 9?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: `A1` will contain only rows or columns, I want both Rows and columns, so that's y `A11`. Right now we are not concerned about when it exceds 9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95697/discussion-between-coder-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DataTable` as `DataSource` and fill it in this way:

```
protected void btnDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // use CompareValidators for the two TextBoxes for rows and columns
    // with it's Operator property set to DataTypeCheck and Type="Integer"
    int rows = int.Parse(txtNoOfRowsRC.Text);
    int columns = int.Parse(txtNoOfColRC.Text);

    grdBinDefinitionDisplay.DataSource = GetDataSource(rows, columns);
    grdBinDefinitionDisplay.DataBind();
}

protected DataTable GetDataSource(int rows, int columns)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    for (int c = 1; c <= columns; c++)
        table.Columns.Add("Column " + c.ToString());

    for (int r = 1; r <= rows; r++)
    {
        DataRow row = table.Rows.Add();
        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        {
            string value = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", IntToLetters(r), r, col.Ordinal + 1);
            row.SetField(col, value);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

I have used this method to generate the letter for the row-number(rewards [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13105/integer-to-alphabet-string-a-b-z-aa-ab)):

```
public static string IntToLetters(int value)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    while (--value >= 0)
    {
        result = (char)('A' + value % 26) + result;
        value /= 26;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This handles the case with *abbrevation as "A-Z"*, you haven't mentioned any other.

Comment: is that to be added under button click ??

Comment: @coder: that has to be added to a method that will be called from the button-click event handler. And of course you need to add `myGridView.DataSource=GetDataTable();myGridView.DataBind();`. Btw, rewards for the `IntToLetter` goes to: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13105/integer-to-alphabet-string-a-b-z-aa-ab

Comment: what is `GetDataTable` here. Here is what I tried https://dotnetfiddle.net/Pz7Uy8

Comment: @code: it was just the method that i have mentioned. In your code it is `DisplayGrid`. But i would give it a different name since it generates and returns the DataSource as `DataTable`. It doesn't show it.

Comment: i have written the method, just i m stuck how to bind the gridview. I m confused with `GetDataTable` :(, Also see my aspx https://dotnetfiddle.net/UcNDuT

Comment: ok. is my aspx fine for the gridview to display.. `<cc1:Grid ID="grdBinDefinitionDisplay" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="300" PageSize="5000"
                    ShowFooter="true" AllowAddingRecords="false" AllowSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    PageSizeOptions="1000" FolderStyle="../Styles/Grid/style_12">
                </cc1:Grid>`

Comment: @coder: you also have to set `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`

Comment: other than that do I need to **add or remove** something from the grid ??

Comment: actually I debug the code, and i got error as `cannot read property firstChild of null`

Comment: @coder: it seems that this error is not related to my code because it's a javascript error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650699/javascript-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-firstchild-of-null

Comment: Its not related to your code but it says that `id` is null or something like that. but i havent used any javascript on the page..isn't it strange ?

Comment: I resolved that error, actually when I debug the code, a blank area was coming on pageload may be that was due to grid. I made `visible= false` and now that error is gone. Now how to make it visible. After `grdBinDefinitionDisplay.DataBind();` right ??

Comment: @coder: i don't know what code you use. That's clearly a javascript issue which isn't related to this question at all. Maybe you should ask a different question according to that new issue. If i use my code on a blank ASP.NET page it works without a problem.

Comment: absolutely it works perfectly. now my gridview is also been displayed. its just the height and width matters. I will look at it by my own. Thanks a lot Tim. the answer is very much perfect. +1 for handling `A-Z` part.

Comment: just one thing, how can we set column `width` from the code behind **here**

Comment: @coder: you can set it in `RowCreated` or `RowDataBound` event. `e.Row` is the `GridViewRow` and `e.Row.Cells` contains all columns. If you want to set the first cell's width: `e.Row.Cells[0].Width = New Unit(120);` (f.e. if you want it to have 120 pixels)

Comment: :Ok got that. One more thing,there is a slight change in the result. Earlier I wanted to look it as `A11` now I want to look it as `A-1-1` how to insert that `-` in between them ?